# Interaction between time-independent and time-dependent covariates in cox model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, interaction, cox-regression

I am running a cox model but I want to add interactions between time-independent and time-dependent covariates in cox model. Is it sensible to do so? If so, what is the way to implement this in R?

I know for time-independent covariates (age and race), this is the model:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(week, arrest) ~ age + race, data = Rossi)
```

And for time-dependent covariates (employed), this is the model:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, arrest.time) ~ employed, data = Rossi.2)
```

My question is does it make sense to interact time-independent covariates (age and race) and time-dependent covariates (employed) in the same cox model using the `Surv(start, stop,..)` command? Like this:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, arrest.time) ~ age:employed + race:employed, data = Rossi.2)
```

If so, does the interpretation of interactions follow the same line as interactions in a regular regression model? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May get more help with this if you add the `[r]` tag to the question

Comment: Thanks @4D45 I just added the r tag

Comment: Here is a good start: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490131/interactions-with-time-dependent-covariates-in-survival-analysis>